# Changing layout through user input

Tags: android, layout, input, android-edittext

Im new to app development.

I want to add a button on the screen that when clicked will give the user a TextEdit in which he can enter some data. Can anyone give a brief description to how this is done?

Comment: In addition I dont want this to link to another activity. I would just like to alter the layout of the activity the user is on.. Thanks in advance guys :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to write all the code from scratch but I can give you a few pointers that should help. You can create a new `EditText` with something like

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
     EditText et = new EditText(v.getContext());
     // add layout params, text, etc...

}
```

Then you need to add it to a `ViewGroup` such as a `LinearLayout` that is in the currently inflated `Layout` with `viewGroupName.addView(et)`;

However, a simpler way, if this works for you, is to have the `EditText` already defined in your xml and set the `visibility` to either `invisible` or `gone` then set the `visibility` in your `onClick()` to `visible`.

Hopefully this is enough to get you started. If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: ok i see the difference between the two and yes you're right. but then that just means that in your second suggestion you only have a finite amount of inputs but the first suggestion is more flexible. Am I right? and also how do you add something to a ViewGroup? a brief description is fine. Thank you alot for responding :D

Comment: I just read your answer more thoroughly, it helped alot thank you

Comment: You are welcome. And there are tons of questions on SO concerning adding view dynamically, adding layout params, and such in case you get stuck.